# BIOS not POSTing

Tags: boot, bios, bsod, hardware-failure

Would I be right to expect main board failure? Win 10 threw a BSOD, had to manually restart, automatic repair kicked in but froze solid. Power cycling the device = no POST. Fan spins, power to ODD but no disk activity or indeed any visual output on monitor or other signs of life. Would clearing CMOS even help?

Comment: "Would clearing CMOS" isn't a thing.

Comment: @Op, this may seem like witchcraft, but completely deprive the box of power for an hour, and try again. I'm always amazed how often that works.

Comment: Start narrowing it down.  Detach everything out but the MB, CPU and PSU. Now start it, does it beep like it has no RAM (or no Video)? If not, then it's either your MB, CPU or PSU that's bad. Start swapping parts with known-good replacements until you find the culprit.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: just for clarity: it may not beep if there's no speaker attached to the motherboard jumpers. Unsure of the OP's knowledgebase

Comment: @Ramhound Sure it is.  The initial question was "Would clearing CMOS even help?"  I understood it.  That means removing the battery to cause the configuration in the CMOS to be reset.

Comment: @FrankThomas: The jargon I'm familiar with is "voodoo magic".  e.g., [jargon file: voodoo programming](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/V/voodoo-programming.html) uses very similar description (particulalry definition #2), and is also similar to .[jargon file: black magic](http://catb.org/jargon/html/B/black-magic.html).  Googling didn't elaborate on witchcraft.  (If you're not familiar with the terms/site, I recommend also [casting the runes](http://catb.org/jargon/html/C/casting-the-runes.html) and [field circus](http://catb.org/jargon/html/F/field-circus.html) just for entertainment value.)

Comment: Removing "Wndows 10" tag; POST issues indicate the cause wasn't an OS issue.  The POST issues cause this to appear to be a hardware problem, so it is quite unlikely that Win10 caused this, and chances are other operating systems would complain as well.  So if someone was searching for Windows 10-related stuff (which is what the tag is for), this question doesn't really fit into that category.

Comment: @TOOGAM - What you describe is restoring CMOS defaults or resetting CMOS.  "Clearing" CMOS indicates one would get rid of it entirely.  Perhaps I am being to strict about the literal meaning of the word, but words have specific meanings.  Using the proper jargon or terminology is important.

Comment: @Ramhound -Proper terminology says that CMOS is not properly the name of the system setup software/firmware, called BIOS on older systems ((U)EFI on newer). Instead, "CMOS" is the common name for memory that stores the configuration details used by the system startup process. More terminology notes: if a bit is "set", the new value is one.  If a bit is "cleared", the new value is zero. You can clear memory, which means all bits start to store zero. Since CMOS is memory & memory can be cleared, "clearing CMOS" is valid terminology.  *After* doing that, BIOS setup resets some settings to default

Answer (score 3):

A POST failure could indicate any hardware failure. Memory, HDD, USB port, Fan etc. Does not necessarily mean main board failure.

Comment: I think the crux here is, whether the POST failed, or failed to run at all. Usually when someone says no-post, I assume that they are saying their box is a paperweight, not that it started and then displayed an error.

Comment: Or, if talking about ACER, could mean that the backup battery has to be replaced. Nothing on screen at all with a dead battery.

Answer (score 0):

New board just pulsed fan in unison with a blinky power LED on motherboard itself. Tried a spare single core Celron D had lying around, everything roared into life! Never had a CPU die before.